# OpenSSL cant use gem "openssl": key must be 32 bytes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl

Maybe title is not so good, but I am desperate and dont know where the problem is.

I need to use gem "openssl", but it still gives me this errors when I start console:

```
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::VERSION
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_LIBRARY_VERSION
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OPENSSL_FIPS
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Config::DEFAULT_CONFIG_FILE
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::Signer
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::TEXT
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOCERTS
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOSIGS
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOCHAIN
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOINTERN
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOVERIFY
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::DETACHED
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOATTR
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOSMIMECAP
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKey::RSA::PKCS1_PADDING
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKey::RSA::SSLV23_PADDING
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKey::RSA::NO_PADDING
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKey::RSA::PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::PKey::EC::NAMED_CURVE
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ExtConfig::HAVE_TLSEXT_HOST_NAME
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ExtConfig::TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::SESSION_CACHE_OFF
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::SESSION_CACHE_CLIENT
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::SESSION_CACHE_SERVER
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::SESSION_CACHE_BOTH
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::SESSION_CACHE_NO_AUTO_CLEAR
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::SESSION_CACHE_NO_INTERNAL_LOOKUP
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::SESSION_CACHE_NO_INTERNAL_STORE
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::SESSION_CACHE_NO_INTERNAL
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::METHODS
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ExtConfig::OPENSSL_NO_SOCK
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_CLIENT_ONCE
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_MICROSOFT_SESS_ID_BUG
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NETSCAPE_CHALLENGE_BUG
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NETSCAPE_REUSE_CIPHER_CHANGE_BUG
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_SSLREF2_REUSE_CERT_TYPE_BUG
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_MICROSOFT_BIG_SSLV3_BUFFER
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_MSIE_SSLV2_RSA_PADDING
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_SSLEAY_080_CLIENT_DH_BUG
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_TLS_D5_BUG
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_TLS_BLOCK_PADDING_BUG
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_DONT_INSERT_EMPTY_FRAGMENTS
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_ALL
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_SESSION_RESUMPTION_ON_RENEGOTIATION
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_SINGLE_ECDH_USE
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_SINGLE_DH_USE
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_EPHEMERAL_RSA
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_TLS_ROLLBACK_BUG
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_SSLv2
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_SSLv3
/Users/jirisverak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@jozu/gems/openssl-2.0.2/lib/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::OP_NO_TLSv1
etc
```

And webpage:
[image]

brew doctor: Your system is ready to brew.
brew info openssl:

```
openssl: stable 1.0.2j (bottled) [keg-only]
SSL/TLS cryptography library
https://openssl.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2j (1,695 files, 12M)
  Poured from bottle on 2017-01-17 at 10:10:07
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/openssl.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: makedepend ✘
==> Options
--universal
    Build a universal binary
--without-test
    Skip build-time tests (not recommended)
==> Caveats
A CA file has been bootstrapped using certificates from the SystemRoots
keychain. To add additional certificates (e.g. the certificates added in
the System keychain), place .pem files in
  /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs

and run
  /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/c_rehash

This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

Apple has deprecated use of OpenSSL in favor of its own TLS and crypto libraries

Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
build variables:

    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig
```

I've tried every possible solution from the SO, internet, space and time. But error is still there. I've reinstalled maybe 10 times rvm, openssl, installed dotnet, etc.

Please can somebody finally help me? Otherwise I will break my Mac and start digging canals :-)

Comment: Why to you add C tag?

Comment: Seems like the warnings in your console might be caused by including/loading the openssl classes twice. Are you sure they are being included once?

Comment: The error in the screenshot looks awfully like https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25185. This should only occur on Ruby 2.4 though. Are you really sure your app is running on Ruby 2.3? In any case, please specify the exact versions of both Ruby and Rails you use.

Comment: @Stargateur What do you mean?

Comment: @Uzbekjon I have only require "openssl" twice in my project.

Comment: @HolgerJust I use Ruby 2.3 (as you can see) but I tried 2.1.9 and the errors are still the same.

Comment: @HolgerJust I forgot. ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin16], Rails 4.2.7.1

Comment: Try requiring "openssl" only once. It appears that it's already been required once from your error message.

Comment: @thesecretmaster I tried. It did not help. How about using gem 'openssl-ccm' instead of openssl?